# What's the Microsoft DI equivalent of Castle.Windsor's DependsOn Dependency.OnValue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, .net-2.0, microsoft-extensions-di

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 library which has DI set up in the following way,

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IMyFactory>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyFactory>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString",
        container.Resolve<IDataAccess>().ConnectionString))
    .LifestyleSingleton());

container.Register(Component.For<IMyAdapter>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyAdapter>().LifestyleTransient());
```

What are the equivalent of these statements in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`?

I want to move away from `Castle.Windsor` dependencies.

Comment: `Services.AddTransient` and `Services.AddSingleton` [transient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) & [singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Please note that your are doing something extremely dangerous in your code example. You resolve from the container during the registration process. This can lead to all kinds of hard-to-spot issues. Most DI Containers nowadays don't even allow this register-resolve-register pattern anymore (MS.DI, for instance, fortunately, doesn't support it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IMyFactory>(sp =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyFactory>(
        sp,
        sp.GetRequiredService<IDataAccess>().ConnectionString));

services.AddTransient<IMyAdapter, MyAdapter>();
```

Comment: For the first one, I am getting an error on the last line, `sp.GetRequiredService<IDataAccess>().ConnectionString));` saying Argument 2 cannot convert from `string` to `System.Type`

Comment: I'd recommend you change your `MyFactory` constructor to take an `IDataAccess` parameter. It's much easier to describe all your dependencies with complex types rather than needing factory methods.

Comment: @tRuEsAtM: There was an error in my answer. I updated my answer. And do note that I do agree with Jeremy on injecting `IDataAccess`. As a matter of fact, it seems that your `ConnectionString` is runtime data. You should prevent [injecting runtime data into your components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/). Best is to inject `IDataAccess` and retrieve the `ConnectionString` only when you start using your `MyFactory`.